Internet not working when using NEPacketTunnelProvider
My goal is that when a request comes in with a specified ip using vpn, it sents to a localhost 8080 web server I created using gcdwebserver.
However, when I configure it as below, and connect to the ip in the browser, it shows web server result I want but I can't access the other site like stackoverflow.com.
let settings: NEPacketTunnelNetworkSettings = NEPacketTunnelNetworkSettings(tunnelRemoteAddress: "77.77.77.77")

settings.dnsSettings = NEDNSSettings(servers: ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"])

let proxySettings: NEProxySettings = NEProxySettings()
proxySettings.httpServer = NEProxyServer(
    address: proxyHost,
    port: proxyPort
)
proxySettings.httpsServer = NEProxyServer(
    address: proxyHost,
    port: proxyPort
)
proxySettings.autoProxyConfigurationEnabled = false
proxySettings.httpEnabled = true
proxySettings.httpsEnabled = true
proxySettings.excludeSimpleHostnames = true
settings.proxySettings = proxySettings

let ipv4Settings: NEIPv4Settings = NEIPv4Settings(
    addresses: [settings.tunnelRemoteAddress],
    subnetMasks: ["255.255.255.255"]
)

ipv4Settings.includedRoutes = [NEIPv4Route.default()]

settings.ipv4Settings = ipv4Settings

So, I set includeRoutes to only allow specified ip as below, and the internet works fine, but access to the specified ip is failed. It shows "connection failed" in the browser.
Am I trying something wrong?
ipv4Settings.includedRoutes = [
    NEIPv4Route(destinationAddress: "77.77.77.77", subnetMask: "255.255.255.255")
]

